multiple node selection of treeView , does not show commands which are supported by all selected nodes

We have created treeview by following sample - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/tree-view-sample/src/testViewDragAndDrop.ts
For vscode.TreeItem We have defined different set of commands , to be shown on right click on node based upon context value set in package.json.
We have also enabled multiple node selection
4)Now we selected 3 nodes, lets say first node support three commands (c1, c2 and c3) , second node support two commands c1 and c2 and third node support one command c1
We right clicked first node , its shows all three commands supported by selected node (c1, c2 and c3) rather than showing commands which are supported by all nodes selected so in this case it should show only c1 command because it is supported by all nodes.
What needs to be done to show only commands which are supported by all nodes selected by  user?

